# Android inside app calendar for appointment reservation

Tags: android, calendar

I need to create an app that can be used for appointment reservation and I don't know what's the best solution for the calendar functionality. I mean, I want my user to have the same functionalities of the built-in android calendar app and be able to create, edit, delete appointments and that the calendar shows itself in either month and week and day layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link for some reference. You can implement these methods corresponding to your app elements after reading this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: That's not what I mean. I don't want to use the Calendar class but for example a Custom CalendarView. Or even better use the built-in phone calendar app. I'm just asking the better approach for this scenario.